# Oauth2 token, handle from JS spa from MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

**About OAuth**.

- **Frontend SPA react**
- **MVC OAuth backend, signs user's into 3rd party providers, works nicely, return token.**

from my SPA I can do window.open and redirect the user to a sign-in page, NB: has to be a new window as xframeoptions is set to deny.

How do I return the token & correlate with SPA, as they are in separate windows/sessions?

options I'm looking at

- **content security policy** - set the caller's domain
- **set same site cookie**

Using [aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers)

[Samples](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.Client)

Startup.cs

```
   public class Startup
{
    private const string policyName = "Cors";

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    private IHostEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRouting();


        services.AddCors(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy(name: policyName, builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })


        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/signin";
            options.LogoutPath = "/signout";
        })


        .AddGitHub(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["GitHub:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GitHub:ClientSecret"];
            options.Scope.Add("user:email");
            options.Scope.Add("read:org");
            options.Scope.Add("workflow");
            options.SaveTokens=true;
            
        });



        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
           // IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        }

        // Required to serve files with no extension in the .well-known folder
        //var options = new StaticFileOptions()
        //{
        //    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        //};
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
        });
        app.UseCors(policyName);

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
      
    }
}
                
            });
```

Authentication Controller

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("~/signin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn() => View("SignIn", await HttpContext.GetExternalProvidersAsync());

        [HttpPost("~/signin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([FromForm] string provider)
        {
            // Note: the "provider" parameter corresponds to the external
            // authentication provider choosen by the user agent.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(provider))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (!await HttpContext.IsProviderSupportedAsync(provider))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            
            // Instruct the middleware corresponding to the requested external identity
            // provider to redirect the user agent to its own authorization endpoint.
            // Note: the authenticationScheme parameter must match the value configured in Startup.cs
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, provider);
        }

        [HttpGet("~/signout")]
        [HttpPost("~/signout")]
        public IActionResult SignOutCurrentUser()
        {
            // Instruct the cookies middleware to delete the local cookie created
            // when the user agent is redirected from the external identity provider
            // after a successful authentication flow (e.g Google or Facebook).
            return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
```

Home Controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("GitHub", "access_token");
            var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("GitHub", "refresh_token");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Home Page (Index.cshtml)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    @if (User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {
        <h1>Welcome, @User.Identity.Name</h1>

        <p>
            @foreach (var claim in Context.User.Claims)
            {
                <div><code>@claim.Type</code>: <strong>@claim.Value</strong></div>
            }
        </p>

        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" href="/signout?returnUrl=%2F">Sign out</a>
    }

    else
    {
        <h1>Welcome, anonymous</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="/signin?returnUrl=%2F">Sign in</a>
    }
</div>
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: #1 Is your oauth server features embedded on your microservice? #2 What is NB? #3 Are you using strictly some oauth2 flow like authorization grant? #4 Why open a new window is required? Gmail, Microsoft, LinkedIn, etc don't do that.

Comment: @JRichardsz, Thanks for respoding, I've posted some code, have been using the examples in the examples link above not sure what type of grant it is, does not say anywhere I could see, I tried with an iframe and got X-Frame-Options:DENY ?

Comment: Your attached sample is for a client, not of oauth provider. After user success signin, what happens? Is the login windows is closed? Do you have the redirect route?

Comment: @JRichardsz, It runs a challenge then, the login window redirects to home and I can get a token, I've added the Authentication controller and Home page, which displays some claims from the token, thanks for looking. )BTW ignore refresh token's it null just testing atm

Comment: Start the auth from client not server. When user clicks login, form React start the authentication, maybe the 3rd part client has a framework like Microsoft has MSAL. When the authentication is done the app redirect to your app and you grab the Bearer token.

Comment: @Max thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

It seems (correct me if I'm mistaken) that the main issue is launching the window for github auth and sending that token back to your site which is a different window (i.e. the parent window of the popup).

One option is to set up your auth request's `redirect_uri` parameter so that the 3rd party identity provider redirects back to a URL on your site (within the popup window), i.e. your ~/signin endpoint. This allows your server-side to grab hold of the tokens and do things like create a session, store a cookie, etc. Cookies set within the popup window will be available to your site in the original window (assuming it's the same domain) once the parent window has refreshed.

Next, once the popup window has been redirected back to your ~/signin endpoint and you've created the session or stored a cookie, etc, you may wish to close that popup and refresh the parent window so that it recognises the cookie / new session. You can do this by returning a page from the ~/signin request (still inside the popup) which includes the following JavaScript:

```
window.opener.document.location.reload();

// alternatively send the user to an authenticated homepage:
window.opener.document.location.href = '/signed-in-user-homepage';

// and then close the popup
window.close();
```

I don't think it's your goal but for completeness, if you wish to perform OAuth authentication/authorisation from the SPA itself, so the server side doesn't get the tokens, you may wish to let a Javascript library like [oidc-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-client) do the heavy lifting. This launches its own window to perform authentication and hands back the token to the calling SPA itself. These tokens are not visible to the server side.

One resource which really helped me figure this out was the IdentityServer4 quickstart for JavaScript clients, worth stepping through if this is your use case:

[OpenID Connect auth from JavaScript clients quickstart](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_javascript_client.html)
[Sample code for the above quickstart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/4_JavaScriptClient)

Once you've got a token on the client side (i.e. in JavaScript), you could pass it to the server side to use to make requests on behalf of the user but this isn't good practice as it impersonation rather than properly delegated authorisation, and you'd need to work out what to do when the access token expires (passing the refresh token to the server side effectively allows your server to impersonate the user indefinitely).

My preference is to allow the server-side to perform an auth-code authorisation flow using AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers, receive the auth code to the ~/signin page, perform the back channel request to get the tokens, use the identity information to create my own profile for the user and perform requests on behalf of the user using authorisation delegated to my service.

Let me know if any of this needs more explaining but hope it's useful as-is.